# Check if object attribute in an array is unique

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have this array:

```
[{category:'Cat A'}, {category:'Cat B'},{category:'Cat A }]
```

I want a function that returns true if two or several keys (category) is the same in the array.

Is there any smart way to do this with underscore? Can't find any in the docs. Or do I need to this manually with loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) function:

```
var arrayUniq = _.uniq(myArray, function(item) { return item.category; });
var isUniq = arrayUniq.length === myArray.length
```

Answer (score 0):

As a new JS programmer, I wanted to solve this problem using only JS. Here is my attempt, please suggest if I'm missing something over here

### Given Object array (or store)

`var storeWithDup = [{category: "Cat A"}, {category: "Cat B"}, {category: "Cat A"}];
var storeWithoutDup = [{category: "Cat A"}, {category: "Cat B"}, {category: "Cat C"}];`

#### 1. Sort Object array using custom comparison function

```
var myComparator = function(value1, value2){
    if(value1.hasOwnProperty("category") &&
        value2.hasOwnProperty("category")){

        if(value1.category < value2.category){
            return -1;
        } else if(value1.category > value2.category){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
};
```

#### 2. Check for duplicate adjacent elements in an array

```
var arrayDuplicateChecker = function(inpArray){
    for(var i = 1; i < inpArray.length; i++){
        if(inpArray[i-1].category == inpArray[i].category){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

#### 3. Helper function to check for duplicate categories in a store

```
var checkForDuplicateCat = function(inpStore){
    // 1. Sort array
    inpStore.sort(myComparator);
    // 2. check for adjacent duplicates
    return arrayDuplicateChecker(inpStore);
};
```

#### Result

```
alert(checkForDuplicateCat(storeWithDup));  // True
alert(checkForDuplicateCat(storeWithoutDup));  // False
```

**Link to** [JS Fiddle: Object array sort and comparator](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitkandhal/fkL01gvt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

My, how complicated we make things.

```
var array = [{category: 'Cat A'}, {category: 'Cat B'}, {category: 'Cat A }],
    groups = _.groupBy(array, 'category');
    duplicated = Object.keys(groups).filter(function(cat) {
        return groups[cat].length>1; 
    });
```

console.log(duplicated);